# SQL combine count results

Tags: sql, count, inner-join, multiple-results

I have two large tables called REQUESTS and OPENISSUES.
One holds request information and the other holds the number of issues per request.

In the REQUESTS table there is a status column that keeps track of the request status.

I'm looking for a Query that counts all records in the OPENISSUES table for all requests that do not have the status set to "Closed"

My query counts all records but does not return the result in one row.
I get the results per request. Anyone has an idea?

**Here is my query:**

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM openissues WHERE openissues.requestID=requests.ID) AS TotalIssues
FROM requests
WHERE requests.status<>'Closed'
```

Any idea is welcome at this point.
Otherwise I will start to count the records in ASP.

Regards,
Frits

Comment: what is your database system? And can you provide the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly what it sounds like you want.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM openissues op, requests rq 
WHERE op.requestID = rq.ID and rq.status <> 'Closed'
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM openissues op INNER JOIN requests rq ON op.requestID = rq.ID
WHERE rq.status <> 'Closed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is simply a join:

```
  SELECT count(*) as TotalIssues
  FROM openissues o
  INNER JOIN requests r ON ( o.requestID = r.ID )
  WHERE r.status != 'Closed'
```

Comment: `!=` is not a valid operator in all DBMS, only in some of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT openissues.requestID)  
FROM openissues
INNER JOIN requests ON openissues.requestID = requests.ID 
WHERE rq.status <> 'Closed'
```

or

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM openissues
INNER JOIN requests ON openissues.requestID = requests.ID 
WHERE rq.status <> 'Closed' 
GROUP BY openissues.requestID
```

These queries will count the number of requestIDs which have at least one record not in the Closed state in the requests table.

*Note to @ypercube*

It will not count the same requestID twice (as bowlturner's might).

Comment: They want a single result, not `GROUP BY` (as in bowlturner's answer.)

Comment: @ypercube - you are probably right, I can't tell from the question.

Comment: *"My query counts all records but **does not return the result in one row.** I get the results per request. "*

Comment: @ypercube - My query did return one row, but I changed it to use the DISTINCT keyword instead of group by which might make you happier. :D

Comment: @ypercube - I should point out, my query will return a different result than bowturner's.  I'm not sure which the OP wants, I would expect my query, which is why I posted it.